# Can I consider check from LLC company as a personal check?

Tags: united-states, small-business, personal-check

I have a friend wanting to send me $10K like as a gift. But he owns an LLC business so he said his LLC bank account and personal bank account is one. It's the same. My question is can I get it like a gift without any risk? Because of my visa, I can't get any money from another company.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that your friend only has a bank account in the name of his company, and not in his own name.

Comment: Is this 'friend' somebody you have actually met, or someone who has contacted you on the web or by email? Be especially careful if your 'friend' asks you to send money to other people, especially by non-reversible means (gift cards, etc) as the cheque may be fake and the money you send will be yours which you will lose. Also you may find yourself in trouble for money laundering.

Comment: I want to buy a house so I need money, which is trusted by the bank, there are money i borrow from him, he can also send cash, i want money from bank. I am just confused about my visa situation and question from the IRS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A business bank account and a personal bank account are very different.  The way you state it, I would not risk a visa violation.  He may use his business account as a personal but the IRS or ICE may look upon it very differently.

People do not normally give out 10K gifts which makes this even more suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it. Even if it were 'ok', you're asking for a lot of trouble. If it's a true gift, then the friend can find a way to give it to you in a form that won't set you up for trouble.

Comment: I want to buy a house so I need money, which is trusted by the bank. I am just confused about my visa situation and question from the IRS.